SVG aliasing issue?
On some screen sizes, the SVG logo adds an odd line to the h character of a.svg graphic. The strangeness vanishes as you zoom in, and on some screen sizes, the issue doesn't even show up. I've been searching for a solution for a while now, but I haven't come across this kind of issue before.
Has this ever happened to anyone before?
You can check it out yourself - here: https://www.rigawhiskyfriends.com/en
View the following examples:




Just a rendering issue with some render engines. I don't think there's a lot one can do about it - perhaps split the paths at the h and overlap the two sides slightly.

Yes lot of buggy SVG renderers out there. There is not much we can do to even verify the issue unless you tell us exactly what svg renderer your using and on which os.

I just checked the link you provided.  I can't reproduce the problem when viewing with Firefox on Win 11. The logo looks perfect.  This may be a rendering bug with the browser you are using, or even specific to your OS. Try using a different browser, a different computer even.  Not something we can really help with here.

On a side note, perhaps also check the construction of the letter. Are there any extra/redundant nodes or overlapping nodes?

I checked the SVG from the web site @BillyKerr - It doesn't appear to be a construction issue.
